# Why are some browsers considering "n°" as 2 different words and how can I prevent word break?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I have to display a string containing "n°######" where # are random numbers.

Chrome & Safari are break the word between n and ° when necessary. Firefox doesn't do it for example.

Any idea how to prevent this knowing that the `word-break` property is no help here.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Wrap your n°###### string in a `<span></span>` and apply `white-space: nowrap;` to it.
2. Replace your degree symbol (`°`) with a superscript 0 (`⁰`) that  doesn't break text.

Comment: I forgot to add, I'm stuck with a generated string that contains the number, so there is no possibility to insert the span.

Comment: You could insert the span using a regular expression replacement.